# Compare each element of list with other elements in list

Tags: android, arraylist, textview

I have two lists

list 1= [Hello How are you]

list 2= [Hello How me you]

I want to compare each element of list 1 to list 2 and then change colour of elements accordingly like matched should be green and unmatched should be red. Please check below image. Output should be like this. Can anyone please tell me how can i do that ?

[image].

Comment: Please post what you have tried by now, post some code. Don't expect that someone will just solve your problem for you. Stack Overflow is about getting a help when you can't solve some problem, not asking someone to do everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by split string on `" "`

```
        String first = "Hello How are you";
                String second = "Hello How me you";

                String[] stringArrayFirst = first.split(" ");
                String[] stringArraySecond = second.split(" ");

                for(int i=0; i< stringArrayFirst.length; i++) {
                    if (stringArrayFirst[i].equals(stringArraySecond[i])) {
                        // use spannable to make this string to green
                  Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(stringArrayFirst[i]);
                wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, stringArrayFirst[i].length()-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// now set wordtoSpan on textview

                    }else {
                        // make it red
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the above..Can you please tell me how can i use spannable here

Comment: I have updated the answer. Kindly accept my answer if it's helpful for you

Comment: It's not working

Comment: not working in what sense? kindly describe your problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Deluxe1 is right you should post what you try and some code before. but your problem was funny so here's my solution.

```
public static CharSequence printDiff(Context context, String sentence1, String sentence2) {
        String[] array1 = sentence1.split(" ");
        String[] array2 = sentence2.split(" ");

        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(sentence1);
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            int colorRes;
            if (i < array2.length) {
                colorRes = array1[i].equals(array2[i]) ? R.color.green: R.color.red;
            } else {
                colorRes = R.color.green;
            }
        int startIndex = getStartIndexOf(array1, i);
        int endIndex = startIndex + array1[i].length();
        sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        return sb;
    }

    public static int getStartIndexOf(String[] array, int index) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            count += array[i].length();
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks..It's working

Comment: Don't forget to kindly accept my answer.

Comment: Sure, it is a simple problem. But I think providing an answer to such a question only encourages this kind of behavior.

Comment: you're right, i did this for the points (i was greedy)

Comment: @ JCDecary Suppose
 String first = "Hello How are you";
 String second = "I am";
Then your code giving array index bound exception
Should i do like this
 for (int i = 0; i < array1.length-2; i++) {
}

Comment: @RahulArora i edited my answer. Please i just gave you a plug and play solution, accept my answer. and for further question try debugging first the probleme was very simple. I'm not here to do your work.

Comment: @ JCDecary Can you please help me..Can you check my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669257/match-multiple-strings-in-android