# Match Multiple Strings in Android

Tags: java, android, string

I have three Strings

String 1= "Hello how are you how was your day"

String 2= "Hello how are you"

String 3= "how was your day"

I want to match each word of string 2 with string 1 and change colour of word accordingly. I have used below code and it's working fine

```
private void printDiff(final Context context, String sentence1, String sentence2) {
        String[] array1 = sentence1.split(" ");
        String[] array2 = sentence2.split(" ");

        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(sentence1);
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            int colorRes;
            if (i < array2.length) {

                    colorRes = array1[i].equalsIgnoreCase(array2[i]) ? R.color.colorPrimary : R.color.colorAccent;


            } else {
                colorRes = R.color.black;
            }
            int startIndex = getStartIndexOf(array1, i);
            int endIndex = startIndex + array1[i].length();
            sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }


    } 

 public static int getStartIndexOf(String[] array, int index) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            count += array[i].length();
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

You can see output in below image

[image]

Now i want to match string 3 with string 1 and i want output like below image because string 2 and string 1 already matched.

[image]

Can anyone please help me. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Do you want to continue matching the string 3 with string 1 where the string 2 finished or do you want it from the beginning of the string 1?

Comment: Do you want to continue matching the string 3 with string 1 where the string 2 finished
...Yes

Comment: As far as I can see there are only two strings `sentence1` and `sentence2`. Where is the string 3?

Comment: yes..Can you please help me how to integrate string 3 in this logic

Comment: why not concatenate string2 & string 3 ? then compare the concatenated string with string 1?

Comment: Yes, i did this..Now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
String text;
String[] pattern;

int matchedSoFar = 0;

while(matchedSoFar < text.length) {
    for(int i = 0; matchedSoFar < text.length and i < pattern.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; matchedSoFar < text.length and j < pattern[i].length; j++) {
            // set color if pattern[i][j] == text[matchedSoFar]
            matchedSoFar++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have the string s1 as `text` and s2 and s3 in `pattern`